# How can i count special character like '?' for each column in my DataFrame in Pandas?

Tags: python, pandas, special-characters

This seems like an easy and simple task, however i'm looking for basic and comprehensive answer to count my missing values in data which they're coded like this '?' character.

My Data:
[image]

I want my answer to be like this:

```
drive_wheels 0
engine_location 0
engine_type 0
num_of_cylinders 0
fuel_system 0
bore 4
stroke 4
```

I tried this :

```
 for i in data.columns:
           counter = 0
           if data[i].dtype == '?':
                counter += 1
           else:
                counter = 1
 print(i, ' ', str(sum(counter)))
```

I would be appreciate if someone can assist me. Thank you!

Comment: please show what you have tried so we can help you, we are not here to do the work for you.

Comment: I'm trying to count my special character in my dataframe in order to remove the rows and columns. i tried this but it doesn't work.

for i in data.columns:
    counter = 0
    if data[i].dtype == '?':
        counter += 1
    else:
        counter = 1
print ( i, ' ' ,str(sum(counter)))

Comment: Can you include the code in the answer so that we can see it better?

Comment: @Holden Yes, i added the code.

Comment: @ruddysimonpour Can you please share a sample of your dataframe?

Comment: @MayankPorwal added

Answer (score 0):

You included the counter variable inside the loop, meaning that every loop you are resetting it to 0. All you have to do is move it outside the loop like this;

```
counter = 0
for i in data.columns:
    if data[i].dtype == '?'
        counter += 1
```

Comment: When i print it it gives me an error such as: " 'int' object is not iterable "

Answer (score 0):

[`Apply`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.apply.html) a function to each column where the serie [`equal`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.eq.html) `?` and sum the `True` results

```
data.apply(lambda serie: serie.eq('?').sum(), axis=0)
```

If for some reason the content is not strictly equal to `?` (for example, it contains additional spaces), use [`contains`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.str.contains.html) method:

```
data.apply(lambda serie: serie.str.contains('\?').sum(), axis=0)
```

Comment: Hard to tell why without data. Can you please run the following line and paste the result in the description of the question: `df.head(10).to_json()`